# Can P2P and all-gather be performed at the same time in pytorch (torch.distributed)?

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning, multi-gpu

I know this might be silly questions for you but I'm new to multi-GPU programming.
I learned that P2P (Point-to-Point communication) can be doned by PCIe and the Collective communication (ex. all-gather, all-reduce) can be doned by NVLink or PCIe.
Then, I wonder is it possible to executing the two operations (P2P and Collective Communication ) at the same time with different CUDA stream in pytorch??